# Is there any spring mvc sitemap provider?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sitemap

Is there any configuration in spring mvc to use sitemap layout for rendering breadcrumbs and the Menu control?
I mean what is the best mechanism in spring mvc to use sitemap layout for rendering breadcrumbs and the Menu/sub Menu control?

There is SiteMesh for decorating spring mvc pages, similarly is there something for sitemap in spring mvc?